# Compare last close to previous candles (pine-script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have the script below that plots a line of the previous candle close

How would I go about comparing that price to the past 50 candles and plotting vertical lines on any candles with the same closing price?

```
//@version=4
study("Candle Close", overlay=true)
cus_color = input(#FFFFFF, "Color")
cus_width = input(1, "Width")

var line lastPriceLine = line.new(0, 0, 0, 0)
line.set_xy1(lastPriceLine, bar_index-500, close[1])
line.set_xy2(lastPriceLine, bar_index, close[1])
line.set_color(lastPriceLine, cus_color)
line.set_width(lastPriceLine, cus_width)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop and loop through last n bars. Then compare each close price in your loop with the last closed price and draw a line if they are the same.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index-1, high, "Close: " + str.tostring(close[1]), yloc=yloc.abovebar, textcolor = color.white)

    for i=2 to 200
        if (close[1] == close[i])
            line.new(bar_index-i, close[i], bar_index-i, close[i] + 1, extend=extend.both)
            label.new(bar_index-i, high, "Close: " + str.tostring(close[i]), yloc=yloc.abovebar, textcolor = color.white)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I'll have to learn v5 to add my original code to this. Is there a way to draw the line only if the following candle goes the opposite direction? (i.e. same closing price but next candle reverses)

Comment: That makes it a little bit more complicated but still possible. You just need to add a couple of checks in the loop.